# Iterate JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am attempting to pull data from an API that returns data as a JSON object. I have the API call which returns data that looks like this (shortened here for brevity's sake)

```
   "status":"OK",
   "copyright":"Copyright (c) 2017 Pro Publica Inc. All Rights Reserved.",
   "results":[
      {
         "num_results": 10,
         "offset": 0,
         "bills": [
              {
                 "bill_id": "hr2739-113",
                 "bill_type": "hr",
                 "number": "H.R.2739",
                 "bill_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/113/bills/hr2739.json",
                 "title": "Efficient Use of Government Spectrum Act of 2013",
                 "sponsor_title": "Rep.",
                 "sponsor_id": "M001163",
                 "sponsor_name": "Doris Matsui",
                 "sponsor_state": "CA",
                 "sponsor_party": "D",
                 "sponsor_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/M001163.json",
                 "gpo_pdf_uri": "http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/BILLS-113hr2739ih/pdf/BILLS-113hr2739ih.pdf",
                 "congressdotgov_url": "https://www.congress.gov/bill/113th-congress/house-bill/2739",
                 "govtrack_url": "https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/113/hr2739",
                 "introduced_date": "2013-07-18",
                 "committees": "House Armed Services Committee",
                 "committee_codes": ["HSAS","HSIF"],
                 "subcommittee_codes": ["HSAS26","HSIF16"],
                 "primary_subject": "Science, Technology, Communications",
                 "summary_short": "Efficient Use of Government Spectrum Act of 2013 - Directs the Federal Communications Commission (FCC), within three years after enactment of the Middle Class Tax Relief and Job Creation Act of 2012, to: (1) reallocate electromagnetic spectrum between the frequencies from 1755 to 1780 megahertz (currently, such frequencies are occupied by the Department of Defense [DOD] and other federal agencies); and (2) as part of the competitive bidding auctions required by such Act, grant new initial lic...",
                 "latest_major_action_date": "2013-08-29",
                 "latest_major_action": "Referred to the Subcommittee on Intelligence, Emerging Threats &amp; Capabilities."
              },
                           {
                 "bill_id": "hr3355-113",
                 "bill_type": "hr",
                 "number": "H.R.3355",
                 "bill_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/113/bills/hr3355.json",
                 "title": "Reducing Employer Burdens, Unleashing Innovation, and Labor Development Act of 2013",
                 "sponsor_title": "Rep.",
                 "sponsor_id": "G000558",
                 "sponsor_name": "Brett Guthrie",
                 "sponsor_state": "KY",
                 "sponsor_party": "R",
                 "sponsor_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/G000558.json",
                 "gpo_pdf_uri": "http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/BILLS-113hr3355ih/pdf/BILLS-113hr3355ih.pdf",
                 "congressdotgov_url": "https://www.congress.gov/bill/113th-congress/house-bill/3355",
                 "govtrack_url": "https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/113/hr3355",
                 "introduced_date": "2013-10-28",
                 "committees": "House Armed Services Committee",
                 "primary_subject": "Economics and Public Finance",
                 "summary_short": "Reducing Employer Burdens, Unleashing Innovation, and Labor Development Act of 2013 - Expresses the sense of Congress that increasing the competitiveness of U.S. manufacturers will strengthen the national economy. Title I: Investing in America&#39;s Workforce - Investing in America&#39;s Workforce Act - Amends the Workforce Investment Act of 1998 to require state or local workforce investment systems to use youth activities funds allocated to a local area for programs that provide training, which may...",
                 "latest_major_action_date": "2014-01-24",
                 "latest_major_action": "Referred to the Subcommittee on Intelligence, Emerging Threats &amp; Capabilities."
              },
```

Using Python, I am trying to loop through the data and return all the values like so:

```py
import requests
import json

r = requests.get({url and credentials here}).text

resp = json.loads(r)


for bill in resp['results']['bills']:
    name = bill['results']['bills']['title']
    type = item['results']['bills']['bill_type']

print(name, type)
```

However, whenever I try to run this, I get

```py
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Why can't I use the list indices as str? There exists plenty of examples that use str.

Comment: A dictionary can be accessed with strings as keys, but a list must use integers or slices (e.g.: `some_list[3:-1]`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'bills' in the json is a list of objects (e.g. `"bills" : [` - the opening bracket is square which implies a list).

You have to use an integer to access an element of a list, so you can say;

```
resp['results'][0]['bills'][0]
```

To access the first bill, for example.

However, your code is a bit confused in your loop, the `bill` variable will contain the information for each bill, so you can reference the keys directly, e.g. to loop over the bills in the first result

```
for bill in resp['results'][0]['bills']:
    name = bill['title']
    type = bill['bill_type']

    print(name, type)
```

The variables 'name' and 'type' will only contain the details of each bill during the loop block.

You can nest loops to loop through all results

```
for result in resp['results']:
  for bill in result['bills']:
      name = bill['title']
      type = bill['bill_type']

      print(name, type)
```

Comment: Perfect! The only edit I had to make was add a colon to the for `for` in the second example on how to nest loops.

Answer (score 0):

`bill` is a json object that does not have `results` or `bills` as a string index. Try the following :

```
for bill in resp['results']['bills']:
    name = bill['title']
    type = item['bill_type']

    print(name, type)
```

Comment: It's not really a JSON object, it's a Python dictionary which acts much the same as a JSON object. `loads` deserialises the JSON string into a Python dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

In json data  `results` is a list of dicts. 
So first iterate over results. 
Then for each result iterate over bills to retrieve the name and type of bill.

```
for result in resp['results']:
    for bill in result['bills']:
        name = bill['title']
        type = item['bill_type']
        print(name, type)
```

Answer (score 0):

also in your code, name equals:

```
name = bill['results']['bills']['title'] -> resp['results']['bills']['results']['bills']['title']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving JSON response please find below two methods of parsing it.

Method 1: Normal way - this is something which you are trying

```
import requests


resp = requests.get(url="url",auth="cred").json()

for bill in resp['results'][0]['bills']:
    bill_name = bill['title']
    bill_type = bill['bill_type']

print(bill_name, bill_type)
```

Method 2 : Cleaner approach of accessing json response

```
for bill_dict in resp.get("results", []):  # returns None if "results" field is not found
    for bill in bill_dict.get('bills', []): 
        bill_name = bill.get('title')  # None is assigned to bill_name if key 'title' is not found
        bill_type = bill.get('bill_type')  # None is assigned to bill_name if key 'title' is not found error OR you can assign default value if key is not found Ex: bill.get('bill_type', 'bill type unavailable')

print(bill_name, bill_type)
```

There are many other ways too.

Comment: For method 2: should be resp.get("results", []) and bill_dict.get('bills', []) because if there's no results or bills you will get None but NoneType object is not iterable.

Comment: You are absolutely correct I had added in my code comment but somehow missed to add that point here, thank you for pointing out.